# Flutter stack alignment issue

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

Good morning, I am trying to align three Widgets by overlapping them with a Stack Widget.

I would like to give the illusion of one single container with two inputs.

I would like that when you select a TextField, the focused border overlapped the divider in the middle.

However, I can't understand why it only works with TextField 1.

[Screenshot](https://i.postimg.cc/cLvNYGgM/Screenshot-1664909947.png)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Join the Containers'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 55.0,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildGroundLayer(),
              _buildDividerLayer(),
              _buildInputLayer(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildGroundLayer() {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.black12,
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.black87,
          width: 2.5,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildDividerLayer() {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 8.0,
            ),
            child: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  right: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    width: 2.5,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: SizedBox(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildInputLayer() {
    return Row(
      children: const <Widget>[
        Flexible(
          flex: 1,
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  width: 2.5,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
                ),
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                  width: 2.5,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
                ),
              ),
              hintText: 'TextField 1',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Flexible(
          flex: 2,
          child: TextField(
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  width: 2.5,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(16.0),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(16.0),
                ),
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                  width: 2.5,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(16.0),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(16.0),
                ),
              ),
              hintText: 'TextField 2',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, all other widgets are stacked but two text fields are in a row filling the screen width. So, their borders won't overlap each other. May I visually represent your code here.

[See my visual representation here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfcJs.png)

So, the optimal way to solve this is to stack two text fields so that text field 1 right border and text field 2 left border are completely overlapped. But, it ain't easy to align them properly. One way to work around is to hide the divider when one of the text fields are tapped so that it creates an illusion. Here is my modified code. Hope that solves your problem. Good day!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  createState(){
    return _MyHomePageState();
  }
}
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final FocusNode _focus1 = FocusNode();
  final FocusNode _focus2 = FocusNode();
  bool hasTextFieldSelected = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focus1.addListener(_onFocusChange);
    _focus2.addListener(_onFocusChange);
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _focus1.removeListener(_onFocusChange);
    _focus1.dispose();
    _focus2.removeListener(_onFocusChange);
    _focus2.dispose();
  }
  
  void _onFocusChange() {
    
    setState((){
      hasTextFieldSelected = _focus1.hasFocus || _focus2.hasFocus;
    });
  }
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Join the Containers'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: SizedBox(
          height: 55.0,
          child: Stack(
            children: <Widget>[
              _buildGroundLayer(),
              _buildDividerLayer(),
              _buildInputLayer(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildGroundLayer() {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.black12,
        border: Border.all(
          color: Colors.black87,
          width: 2.5,
        ),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildDividerLayer() {
    return Row(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
      children: <Widget>[
        const Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: SizedBox(),
        ),
        Visibility(
        visible: !hasTextFieldSelected,
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 8.0,
            ),
            child: Container(
              decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                border: Border(
                  right: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.black87,
                    width: 2.5,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        const Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: SizedBox(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }

  Widget _buildInputLayer() {
    return SizedBox(
    height: 55,
    child: Row(
      children: <Widget>[
        Expanded(
          flex: 1,
          child: TextField(
            focusNode: _focus1,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              isCollapsed: false,
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  width: 2.5,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
                ),
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                  width: 2.5,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(16.0),
                ),
              ),
              hintText: 'TextField 1',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Expanded(
          flex: 2,
          child: TextField(
        focusNode: _focus2,
            decoration: const InputDecoration(
              enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.transparent,
                  width: 2.5,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(16.0),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(16.0),
                ),
              ),
              focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderSide: BorderSide(
                  color: Colors.orangeAccent,
                  width: 2.5,
                ),
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(16.0),
                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(16.0),
                ),
              ),
              hintText: 'TextField 2',
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

[See result 1 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GD2N0.png)
[See result 2 here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0PnoN.png)

Comment: It worked! Thank you very much :) Yes, it is very hard aligning the Divider and the TextField's borders because those inputs must be flexible in order to adjust themselves to screen size and so they ignores the underlying divider width. I tried to think something about Flexible width plus half of Divider width but it didn't work because Expanded takes all available space. How could you align them dynamically and perfectly? Thanks again and have a nice day :)

Comment: If you wanna do the optimal way, consider using fixed widths for text fields, borders and divider instead of flexible or expanded widget. Only after that, you can easily compute to align them like this - stack first text field's right border and second text field's left border on a divider of the same width with the border. But they won't be responsive. So you have to compute them for multiple screen sizes. I know it sounds a little bit complicated. So, take the easier way if you're ok with it.

Comment: If I understand correctly, in order to design a new custom widget it is preferable to build it with fixed default sizes and behavior and only then make it responsive by using the MediaQuery object to alter its inner fixed sizes based on the current screen, right? Sorry, I'm still learning Front-end development with Flutter, thanks for the patience :)